# What causes drastic change in runtime in this Java snippet?

Tags: java, performance, caching

**Edit**
Please note I am running this code by

```
javac Main.java; java Main
```

between tries.

This is the code I have.. It takes around ~4000 ms in my laptop to run..

```
public class Main {

  public static int findFibonacci(int n) {
    int result;
    if (n == 0) {
      result = 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
      result = 1;
    } else {
      result = findFibonacci(n - 1) + findFibonacci(n - 2);
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(findFibonacci(45));
    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((finish - start));
  }
}
```

Now when I introduce a cache, and store the results for `n` (`cache.put(n, result);`), (but never read it for now), i.e.

```
public class Main {

  static Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

  public static int findFibonacci(int n) {
    int result;
    if (n == 0) {
      result = 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
      result = 1;
    } else {
      result = findFibonacci(n - 1) + findFibonacci(n - 2);
    }

    cache.put(n, result);
    
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(findFibonacci(45));
    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((finish - start));
  }
}
```

Before reading any further, what would be your best guess at how much of a difference it makes if the baseline is 4,000ms? 4,050? 5,000? Well on my machine, runtime jumps 10x, i.e. to ~40,000ms range.. What happened? How costly is putting values to a Map?

OK, now lets make use of the cache and introduce a cache read, i.e. add the following portion:

```
if (cache.containsKey(n)) {
  return cache.get(n);
}
```

```
public class Main {

  static Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

  public static int findFibonacci(int n) {
    if (cache.containsKey(n)) {
      return cache.get(n);
    }

    int result;
    if (n == 0) {
      result = 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
      result = 1;
    } else {
      result = findFibonacci(n - 1) + findFibonacci(n - 2);
    }

    cache.put(n, result);

    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(findFibonacci(45));
    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((finish - start));
  }
}
```

Now, what would be your guess this time? How long to run? Remember the initial runtime was 4,000ms and when we introduced `cache.put` it jumped to 40,000ms.. So given 50% cache hit, maybe it should be 2,000ms + 20,000ms ~= 22,000ms? Well in my case, it goes down to 1ms. Result (which is `1134903170`) is printed instantaneously..

Can someone explain why introducing the cache (but never reading from it) changes the runtime so drastically given we only introduced a `cache.put` which I thought was very cheap? And how come reading from cache made so much difference that the program is now running in an instant. Should not it at least run for 2,000ms?

Comment: "*what would be your best guess at how much of a difference it makes if the baseline is 4,000ms? 4,050? 5,000?*" - The question - as is - is pointless. There is a manifold of factors that influence the in-/decrease. --- Have you used a profoiling tool like [VisualVM (`visualvm.github.io`)](https://visualvm.github.io/) to analyze the execution?

Comment: The JVM optimizes code as it keeps running.  Code naturally gets faster over time.  This is why measurement is extremely hard.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I do not keep it running, I start it fresh everytime. Does it keep optimizations across runs?

Comment: @KorayTugay Look up JIT compilation. During the execution, the JVM will hot-compile code.

Comment: @Turing85 I am calling `javac Main.java; java Main` every time, I do not understand how JIT is relevant here. I do not have a long running Java process where I run a for loop and question why it takes faster to run the same method in subsequent calls.

Comment: As I said: look up JIT compilation.

Comment: @Turing85 I do not understand how JIT compilation causes the execution to jump to 40,000ms from 4,000 ms between #1 and #2.. I would highly appreciate if you have a more concrete answer explaining what is happening in this very specific case and share your knowledge. I fail to come to a conclusion by "looking up JIT compilation"..

Comment: Your cache insertion involves memory allocation.

Comment: @ArfurNarf But that should be the case in scenario #3 too isn't it? I am trying to understand how the runtime can drastically drop in #3.. If adding the `cache.put` statements are costly, how come case #3 runs so fast?

Comment: A cache hit preempts repeated recursion; count the depth to see.

Comment: @trashgod I did add some code to count. I get ~40 cache hits and ~40 cache misses.

Comment: I suspect that autoboxing might be a part of the problem.

Comment: @KorayTugay: Now compare total calls to `findFibonacci` in the second and third examples.

Comment: @Turing85: I agree with your point about JIT compilation affecting results; but in this case, [_memoization_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) dominates.

Comment: @trashgod :facepalm: I understand now.. Thank you.. This is embarrassing.. Method call count decreases from 3672623805 to 89.. :facepalm: I understand where I was confused now, but not sure how I can explain it. Thank you, that clarifies it.

Comment: @trashod Of course 3672623805 calls to `cache.put` will make the execution jump significantly.. I was assuming it was ~80 calls only, not sure why! Thank you for clarifying..

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: @trashgod your argument is valid for the 3rd case. For the 2nd case, however, memorization has zero effect since we only write to the map (and the write - per documentation - should be `O(1)`). For the second case, it seems that the "complexity" hidden behind `O(1)` is pretty large. A CPU-sampled run showed that a large chunk of the time is - in fact - spent in `HashMap`'s `putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent, boolean evict)`-method. I should have stated that my comments were concerend with the 2nd case.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as advised in comments..

My mistake was thinking first call to `findFibonacci(n - 1)` would end up making 45 calls and `findFibonacci(n - 2)` would also end up making another 45 calls. That is clearly wrong as I did not think of `findFibonacci(n - 1)` making yet two another recursive calls, and not one. That is why I assumed the execution would get slower by a very little margin in case #2..

Apparently, without caching, for the input `45` we end up making `3672623805` calls. That explains why the runtime jumps so much in case #2.. Running

```
Map<Long, Long> myMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Long i = 0L; i < 3672623805L; i++) {
  myMap.put(5L, 5L);
}
```

takes around ~30,000ms on my machine, so there is that..

And when the cache is introduced, we drastically reduce the method calls with caching. Since my assumption of number of recursive calls were wrong to begin with, I failed to see the performance gain that would come from the reduction of the number of calls.

Comment: Also, one problem might be the fact that many same keys are inserted in the hashmap  in the example which reduces the performance of the Hash table as stated in its documentation, and the problem may come from the hash function itself

Comment: Note that in this case instead of a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, a `int[] cache = new int[100]` can serve as a cache just as well. `cache[n] = result;` saves a value to the cache. `int v = cache[n]; if (v > 0) return v;` uses a cached value. Even if you remove the 'use the cache if it is there', that only inflates your runtime by ~10%, instead of the 1000% with the map.

Comment: @BlackBear None of that is relevant here. No, a hashmap does not get slower if you overwrite the same key a few billion times. Instead of writing comments that make crazy claims like that, you learn a lot more by giving that a try (and, for performance testing, you really need JMH). The hash function if `Integer` is, obviously, not a problem either. Nothing in your comment is in any way relevant to the stated problem.

Comment: @rzwitserloot then please explain me this doc part taken from HashMap - Note that using
 * many keys with the same {@code hashCode()} is a sure way to slow
 * down performance of any hash table. To ameliorate impact, when keys
 * are {@link Comparable}, this class may use comparison order among
 * keys to help break ties.

Comment: @BlackBear it does **not** mean "*many same keys*", as from your first comment; but "*many keys with the same `hashCode`*", but different keys, so that each key must be saved in the map (same bucket since same `hashCode`)

Comment: @BlackBear to put user85421 in exacting specification: If you call `.put(a0, k, v)` - `.put(a100000, v)` where each `ax` argument has the property that `a1.equals(a2)`, hashmap does not get slower at all. However, if each `ax` has the property that `!a1.equals(a2)`, but, `a1.hashCode() == a2.hashCode()`, things get slow real fast. This is literally NOT POSSIBLE for integers - in Integer's case, `a.equals(b)` and `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` are equivalent. You can't have 2 integer objects with the same hashcode but not `.equals` to each other.